# HTML - avoid colspan in tfoot

Tags: html, html-table

I'm building a Table html framework in which export option are available in tfoot. I want to have only one TD in my tfoot without using a colspan. It's a framework in which the developer just have to set the THEAD and TBODY.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't get the question ... may you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

No. To avoid the problem, don’t use `tfoot` but an element after the table (wrapped in a container together with it if needed for some purpose).